# Wheel view android button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator, android-widget

I am using kankan's wheel view demo. But dont know how to use button when items been choosen in wheel. please help me.

I used a button,but like spinner, there is no method setOnItemSelectedListener(this); So how to use that when button is clicked after selecting the items from wheel.

Thanks in advance.

Coding are as follows:

public class SlotMachineActivity extends Activity {

```
final String cities[] = new String[] { "Item 1",
        "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4",
        "Item 5", "Item 6", "Item 7",
        "Item 8", " Item 9", "Item 10" };

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.slot_machine_layout);



    initWheel(R.id.slot_1, cities);


}

Handler handlar = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        mixWheel(R.id.slot_1);
    }
};

class UpdateTimeTask extends TimerTask {
    public void run() {
        handlar.removeCallbacks(this);
        handlar.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}

// Wheel scrolled flag
private boolean wheelScrolled = false;

// Wheel scrolled listener
OnWheelScrollListener scrolledListener = new OnWheelScrollListener() {
    public void onScrollingStarted(WheelView wheel) {
        wheelScrolled = true;
    }

    public void onScrollingFinished(WheelView wheel) {
        wheelScrolled = false;
        // updateStatus();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cities[wheel.getCurrentItem()], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
};

// Wheel changed listener
private OnWheelChangedListener changedListener = new OnWheelChangedListener() {
    public void onChanged(WheelView wheel, int oldValue, int newValue) {
        if (!wheelScrolled) {
            // updateStatus();
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Initializes wheel
 * 
 * @param id
 *            the wheel widget Id
 */
private void initWheel(int id, String cities[]) {

    ArrayWheelAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayWheelAdapter<String>(this,
            cities);

    WheelView wheel = getWheel(id);
    wheel.setViewAdapter(adapter);
    wheel.setCurrentItem((int) (Math.random() * 10));
    wheel.setVisibleItems(7);

    wheel.addChangingListener(changedListener);
    wheel.addScrollingListener(scrolledListener);
    wheel.setCyclic(true);
    wheel.setEnabled(true);
}

/**
 * Returns wheel by Id
 * 
 * @param id
 *            the wheel Id
 * @return the wheel with passed Id
 */
private WheelView getWheel(int id) {
    return (WheelView) findViewById(id);
}

/**
 * Mixes wheel
 * 
 * @param id
 *            the wheel id
 */
private void mixWheel(int id) {
    WheelView wheel = getWheel(id);
    wheel.scroll(-350 + (int) (Math.random() * 50), 2000);

}
```

}

Comment: And how exactly should people here know, without even a link to the library. And even then, they won't be able to tell you anything else than what you can also find in there.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set a OnClickListener on the button and from there read the currently selected items from the wheel.